# How to save on off conditions in a switch to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure a similar question has been asked before. If so please point it out.

Of course I am new to this field. So please bear with me.

I have a html webpage which contains 6 switches.

I need to save on and off conditions of those switches into different variables.

on = 1
off = 0

As an instance, switch 1 on/off conditions represents x variable.

```
 when on x=1 off x=0
```

switch 2 on/off conditions represents y variable.

```
 when on y=1 off y=0
```

my page views as follows.

[image]

My code:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders
    .slider.round {
      border-radius: 34px;
    }
    
    .slider.round:before {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    */
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label name="s" class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
</label>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
</label>
```

Can someone help me to save these switch conditions into different variables? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: I don't see the JavaScript, can you please post it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a JavaScript function to handle the switch change:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var switchValues = { };
function switched (switchElement) {
  switchValues[switchElement.id] = switchElement.checked;
}
</script>
```

Then make sure each of your checkbox switches has a unique `id` attribute and `onclick` handler assigned to your new function:

```
<label name="s" class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" onclick="switched(this)" checked>
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label><br><br>

    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch2" onclick="switched(this)" checked>
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label><br><br>

    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch3" onclick="switched(this)" checked>
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label><br><br>

    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch4" onclick="switched(this)" checked>
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label><br><br>

    Etc...
```

Comment: i deleted my answer. i was running into errors while testing. this code seems to work. Great job @willman

Answer (score 0):

I have added the use of LocalStorage to keep switch positions

values are inside **switchList** object:

```
const switchList = 
      {​ switch_1: true
      ,​ switch_2: true
      ,​ switch_3: true ​
      , switch_4: true
      ,​ switch_5: true
      ,​ switch_6: true
      }
```

diretly build from the input checkbox list

You also need a form!

so when form element get any input change, by using event delegation you can set the checkbox value inside the switchList

then the switchList is copied into local storage

```js
const switchersF  = document.querySelector('form#switchers')
  ,   memoSwitch = 'SwitchStorage'
  ,   switchList = [...switchers.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')].reduce((s,el)=>{ s[el.name]=true;return s},{})
  ;
initSwitchs()
  ;
switchersF.onsubmit=e=>e.preventDefault() // disable submit form
  ;
switchersF.oninput=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('input[type=checkbox]')) return
  switchList[e.target.name] = e.target.checked
  setSwitchsMemo()
  // console.log( switchList )
  }
function initSwitchs()
  {
  let SwitchsMemo = localStorage.getItem(memoSwitch)

  if (!SwitchsMemo)
    { setSwitchsMemo() }
  else
    {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries( JSON.parse(SwitchsMemo) ))
      {
      switchersF[key].checked = value
      }
    }
  }
function setSwitchsMemo()
  {
  localStorage.setItem(memoSwitch, JSON.stringify(switchList) )
  }
```

```css
#switchers label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  margin: .5em 1em;
  }
#switchers input {
  display: none;
  }
#switchers span {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  }
#switchers span:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  }
#switchers input:checked+span {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  }
#switchers input:checked+span:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
  }
#switchers input:focus+span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<form id="switchers">
  <label> <input type="checkbox" checked name="switch_1"> <span></span> </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" checked name="switch_2"> <span></span> </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" checked name="switch_3"> <span></span> </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" checked name="switch_4"> <span></span> </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" checked name="switch_5"> <span></span> </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" checked name="switch_6"> <span></span> </label>
</form>
```